# spring xd how to get file from s3 or s3 source

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-xd

I am trying to create a  spring xd stream to read a file from s3 its a http link from amazon s3. How to do it in spring xd to read a http  txt file in  s3. currently i am dropping file in /tmp/filetest  it works with below  stream.I want to get the file from http link in s3

```
stream create --name filetest --definition "file --outputType=text/plain | rabbit" --deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Namaste @constantlearner,

This is an interesting challenge, that we are currently solving for a client as well. I stumbled upon your question looking for answers.

To me it looks like S3FS (https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) is by now the most straight-forward solution: mount your S3 bucket into one/more client machines and stream your files with Spring XD, Flume, Spark, etc from there. Otherwise you'd to implement the S3 protocol by yourself.

Kind regards, Daniel.